# Mail blocked by firewall

Tags: java, linux, sendmail, firewall

I've got a problem with the firewall of my server. I'm trying to use sendmail to send email from my server but when the firewall is activated it's not possible. I found the following error in my log:

> Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.infomaniak.ch, 25; timeout -1

When my firewall is disable everything is ok and my mail is send. So I tried to open the port 25 in output in the firewall but nothing change I've always the same problem.

Here is my code:

```
public void envoyerMailSMTP(ArrayList<String> to, ArrayList<String> cc, ArrayList<String> bcc, String from, String subject, String body, String attachment, String attachmentName) throws Exception {

        this.catalog = (Catalog)lookupEjb("CatalogLocal", true);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", this.catalog.getFirst(this.catalog.findByKey("SMTP_HOST_NAME")).getCatalogValue());
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        // uncomment for debugging infos to stdout
        // mailSession.setDebug(true);
        try {
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

            // Ajout de l'expéditeur du mail
            if(from != null && !from.isEmpty()){
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            }

            // Ajout de(s) destinataire(s) du mail
            for(String s : to){
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(s));
            }
            // Ajout de(s) destinataire(s) du mail en cc
            if(cc != null && cc.size() > 0){
                for(String s : cc){
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(s));
                }
            }
            // Ajout de(s) destinataire(s) du mail en bcc
            if(bcc != null && bcc.size() > 0){
                for(String s : bcc){
                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(s));
                }
            }

            // Set Subject: header field
           message.setSubject(subject);

           // Create the message part 
           BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

           // Fill the message
           messageBodyPart.setText(body);

           // Create a multipart message
           Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

           // Set text message part
           multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
           // Part two is attachment
           messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
           DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachment);
           messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
           // Set the name of the attached file
           messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentName);
           multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


           // Send the complete message parts
           message.setContent(multipart);

           transport.connect(this.catalog.getFirst(this.catalog.findByKey("SMTP_HOST_NAME")).getCatalogValue(),
                              this.catalog.getFirst(this.catalog.findByKey("SMTP_AUTH_USER")).getCatalogValue(),
                              this.catalog.getFirst(this.catalog.findByKey("SMTP_AUTH_PWD")).getCatalogValue());

           transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
           transport.close();

        }catch (MessagingException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
```

I tried also to modified my code to use the port 587 and opened it on the firewall, but it wasn't better.

I have a Linux server and I use ufw as firewall.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you try using sendmail directly from the command line? What do you mean with `... but it was better`? Better than what, better in what way?

Comment: Yes, i've tried before and the mail isn't send too in command line

Comment: Well, then I'd say the problem is not your Java code but your system or firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're blocking outgoing traffic by default, then you'll need to enable connections from all source ports to destination port 25. SMTP makes connections from a random port on your host, to port 25 on the server, so you can't just open port 25 outgoing. If it's a non-root user making the connection, then you could just open ports 1024-65545 because non-root users can't open ports < 1024

You can allow outgoing connections with:

```
ufw default allow outgoing
```

Comment: I've tried to do so by opening the port 25 like this : sudo ufw allow out 25 but it doesn't work

Comment: Allowing just port 25 outbound won't work - you have to open all ports because the connection is made from a random port on your server to port 25 on the destination server.